# Integration - which way to solve ?

Tags: integration

I have this question -

$$\int x^3 (\frac{1}{x} -2)^3 $$

I have tried substitution and which ever number I use , it will not cancel out .

Does that mean I have to expand this ?

$$(\frac{1}{x} -2)^3$$

Comment: It certainly means you ought to to try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$
x^3\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)^3=\left(x\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)\right)^3=
(1-2x)^3
$$
Let $u=1-2x$ so that $\mathrm{d}u=-2\,\mathrm{d}x$. Hence, the integral becomes

$$
\begin{align}
I=\int (1-2x)^3\mathrm{d}x&=-\frac{1}{2}\int-2(1-2x)^3\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int u^3\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}u^4\right)+C\\
&=-\frac{1}{8}u^4+C\\
&=-\frac{1}{8}(1-2x)^4+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a full expanding:
$$x^3\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)^3=(1-2x)^3=1-6x+12x^2-8x^3$$ and after this, to calculate the integral.